# vite not including custom components in build, but dev works fine

Tags: build, vite

I'm using a custom html component installed with a simple `npm install --save my-component` in a vue app.  Installed dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@my-component": "^0.0.1",
    "vue": "^3.4.15",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.0.3",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx": "^3.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.3.0",
    "vite": "^5.0.11",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.8.27"
  }
```

In main.ts I import defineCustomElements from my-component and run it.  Then in my vue file I can just add  to the template.  When I do `npm run dev` my vue app loads, the custom component is loaded and displayed, and I can interact with it just as I would expect.

I can see the files in my node_modules directory, but they don't get moved into the dist folder nor do they show up transpiled in to the js files.  At least as far as I can tell.  When I put the files on the server I get a 404 error that my-component.entry.js is not found.

Any ideas as to why that might be happening?  It is just weird that everything works locally with just `vite` but the `vite build` doesn't produce the same output.

But when I do `npm run build` the component's files aren't in the dist folder